# Setting up Rescue and Redis without Rails

Tags: redis, resque, ruby-1.9.3

I know this is a rather vague question, and not really a programming problem, but I'm struggling a bit to set up a Resque system.

The problem I have is the following:

I know how to write the Jobs that can be pushed to our Queue system. We rely on Modules with the **perform** method defined so it can be executed by the Worker. I'm able to write the Ruby code so it works using Gems etc....

However, we do not depend on Rails. I just have a small Ruby application that should "load" the environment of the application. This means running some init script to configure variables for memcache, redis and Sequel.

We have an older version running using monit.d to monitor the queue's and keep them running. To keep the post short, what I'm looking for is information on writing some sort of "application" that can be used as base for the Queue system. It's not a Rails application, but it should be able to do the following:

- Run the Jobs (defined in code) by polling the Queues
- Define new Jobs
- Start and stop the entire worker pool (Rake tasks prefered)
- Not depend on Rails

I'm aware the question is a bit blurry, but I don't know how to describe it better.
Hope someone can provide some insight on how to tackle this problem.